# Call Oracle stored procedure in nhibernate with only scalar return value

Tags: oracle, nhibernate

This is nhibernate mapping:

```
 <sql-query name="SEL_COUNT" >
      <return-scalar column="V_DebtorCount" type="Int32"/>
      { call SEL_COUNT(:V_USER_ID) }
 </sql-query>
```

This is call to stored procedure:

```
    private static int GetAllCount(string userID, ISession session)
    {     
           IQuery query = session.GetNamedQuery("SEL_COUNT")
                .SetParameter("V_USER_ID", userID);       
      return query.UniqueResult<Int32>();
    }
```

I am getting this error:

> ERROR [HY000] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
>   PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SEL_COUNT'
>   ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
>   PL/SQL: Statement ignored

This is the stored procedure:

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE SEL_COUNT
(
 V_DebtorCount OUT NUMBER,
V_USER_ID IN VARCHAR2
)AS
BEGIN
  SELECT Count(*) INTO V_DebtorCount FROM DBR d
          JOIN YCLI ON DBR_ENT = US_CLI                 
          where USR_CODE=V_USER_ID
END SEL_COUNT;
```

Comment: Did you used `UniqueResult`to execute the stored procedure?

Comment: yes i have  IQuery query = session.GetNamedQuery("SEL_DBR_ALL_COUNT")
                    .SetParameter("V_USER_ID", userID);
                return query.UniqueResult<Int32>();